# Python: int object is not iterable when try to cast int to list

Tags: python

Trying to check if `value` is `list`, then convert this list to comma separated string, otherwise use `value` as is:

```
def one():
    val = 1
    v = (val, ','.join(map(str, val)))[isinstance(val, list)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one()
```

But having error:  `'int' object is not iterable`

if `val=[1,2]`, `v=1,2`

Comment: how about `val = 1,` that would make it into `tuple`

Comment: The issue is that your tuple pre-computes both options first, and the `map` operation fails for an `int`. This is rather an archaic and not so readable way to do this, use if-else, or the ternary operator rather than indexing the bool

Comment: A bit OT but what if `val` is a `tuple`, `set` or any other iterable ?

Comment: i use `list` when `val` is like `[1,2]` or ['test`, `test2`]

Comment: "check if value is list, then convert this list to comma separated string" but what you are doing now is, _first_ you convert to a comma-separated string, and _then_ you check whether it's a list, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you can create a function like:

```
def get_value(x):
    return ','.join(map(str, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x
    #                ^ To type-cast each element of list to a string
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> get_value(123)
123
>>> get_value([1, 2, 3])
'1,2,3'
```

However I'll suggest to use a `collections.Iterable` to check the object type which will return True for all the iterators (like list, tuple, string, etc) and not just list. Hence your function should be:

```
from collections import Iterable

def get_value(x):
    return ','.join(map(str, x)) if isinstance(x, Iterable) else x
```

Comment: tried `(.. , ..)[]` like short `if-else` expression, using `','.join(map(str, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else x` solved my trouble

Answer (score 2):

Python is not lazy (there) so the join is executed no matter what value is accessed. Why not

```
if isinstance(val, list):
    val = ",".join(map(str, val))
```

?

Comment: If `val` is an `int` it will do nothing, because then `val` is not an instance of list. If val is an int, it will be unchanged, if it is a list it will be changed to a comma seperated string. Or do you get an error executing this?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that map have this signature **map(function, iterable, …)**,

meaning that the second argument must be iterable type - > int is not iterable and that is why you get the error.